# Visual Studio 2012: Script diagnostics permissions

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I cannot find a description of this online anywhere. When I attempt to run & debug an ASP.NET MVC3 project, I receive this prompt from Visual Studio 2012 Pro. I would like to know:

1. What are these "script diagnostics" it is talking about?
2. What permissions changes is it going to make? is it modifying my project directory or a visual studio installation directory or other? I don't want to 'OK' this until I know what it's doing and where it's doing it.

[image: Script diagnostics permissions]

Comment: The Microsoft answer to this is to [run Visual Studio as Administrator](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05aa5c0a-4a71-440e-9a85-ba9ff5829ed6/project-will-not-run-with-debugging?forum=vssetup). What a joke!